# Binding collections to views in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, javascript-framework

I am new to backbone and I am stuck with this problem where I need to bind a Collection to a view. Is there a way to do this in Backbone or do I have to iterate through my Collection and then bind individuals models to views? All the examples I found online go through these lines of iterating through the collection (like http://liquidmedia.ca/blog/2011/02/backbone-js-part-3/ ).

If this is the way to do it in Backbone, then my other question is whether there is another framework that does a better job for binding to Collections.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All model events are delegated to the collection as well. So instead of binding to each models change event you could just bind to the collections change event. Whenever a model changes the collection triggers the event as well and gives you the model that triggered the event as callback argument.

Comment: ok .. but that still means that you need to pass the Model NOT the collection to the View, after that any change to the model can be reflected in the Collection, but can't I just bind to the collection and then it sorts itself out? My problem with this is that I will always have a ParentView and ChildViews, like in the ToDo example where the ParentView is the AppView, but in a slightly more complicated application you will have a lot ParentViews and ChildViews.

Comment: bind the collection instance, (collection:collectionInstance) to the view, then add this.collectionInstance.on('change', someFunction, this) to your View initialize() method